# SQL show entries where a specific field shows up multiple times

Tags: sql, sql-server

First off here is the data that I am currently using:

**Name, Phone, Email & InvoiceCost**

I am trying to write a query that selects the Name, Phone & Email details where

- The user (identified by email) has made 2 or more purchases within the last 180 days
- The total cost of all of the invoices within these 180 days comes up to over 500

Below is the SQL that I have come up with so far but I doubt that will be of any use at all:

```
SELECT Name, Phone, Email, InvoiceCost
FROM INVOICE JOIN
    (SELECT INVOICE.Email, count(*) AS TotalCount,
     SUM(
         CASE WHEN INVOICE.InvoiceDate >= (GETDATE() - 180) 
              THEN 1 
              ELSE 0 
         END) AS LastSixMonths
     FROM INVOICE
     GROUP BY INVOICE.Email) e
ON INVOICE.Email = e.Email
WHERE (e.TotalCount > 1 AND e.LastSixMonths = 1);
```

I can't figure out how to incorporate the total cost part, please help!

Comment: What is the problem with the query you posted? Any errors?

Comment: I've not used the HAVING clause before, and apologies the Invoice Date doesn't actually need to be displayed, just copied it in there without thinking. Only need the Name, Email and Phone to be displayed.

Thanks.

Comment: First, please add the tag for the database server you are actually using (exa: SQLServer, MySQL, Access, Oracle...)  Second, it's generally a good idea when seeking help on a query that you post the relevent table layouts.

Comment: GETDATE()'s sql server

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you would consider unique combinations of Name, Phone, and Email as individual customers:

```
SELECT Name, Phone, Email, Count(*) AS TotalCount, Sum(InvoiceCost) AS TotalCost
FROM INVOICE
GROUP BY Email, Name, Phone
WHERE DateDiff(d, InvoiceDate, GETDATE()) <= 180
HAVING Count(*) >= 2 OR Sum(InvoiceCost) > 500.0
```